# How to set header, with `\leftmark` not set by `\chapter*` environment, and manual setting cleared by `\printacronyms`?

Tags: chapters, glossaries, fancyhdr, acronyms, glossaries-extra

`\leftmark` and `\rightmark` aren't being set, so I manually do this:

```
\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
\fancyhf[HRE,HLO]{\nouppercase{Acknowledgements}}
\phantomsection
\input{Acknowledgements}

\fancyhf[HRE,HLO]{\nouppercase{Acknowledgements}} % Added just for kicks
```

Then below I can just:

```
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhf[HLE,HRO]{\thepage}
\fancyhf[HRE,HLO]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}

\printacronyms
```

Unfortunately that last page preceding the acronyms is missing a chapter name (it just shows a page number).

Full runnable example:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fncychap}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[acronym,xindy,toc,nomain]{glossaries}

\setlength{\headheight}{15.2pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}


\makeglossaries
%\setacronymstyle{long-sc-short}

\newacronym{AB}{AB}{Alpha Beta}

\begin{document}

\title{\LaTeX{}}
\author{Author's Name}

\maketitle

\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
\fancyhf[HRE,HLO]{\nouppercase{Acknowledgements}}
\phantomsection
Hello

\newpage
 world!
\fancyhf[HRE,HLO]{\nouppercase{Acknowledgements}}

\newpage

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhf[HLE,HRO]{\thepage}
\fancyhf[HRE,HLO]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\printacronyms


\end{document}
```

Is there a non-hacky solution to this, i.e.: a proper way to set `\leftmark` when using `\chapter*{}`? - Or just a way to get the current version working?

Comment: Could you please post  a short, but complete, compilable code demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Okay, I have now done so.

Comment: If you add `\clearpage` or `\newpage` before `\printacronyms`, that will avoid the resetting before it's too late.

Comment: I tried above, below, and in both places: `\clearpage\newpage\fancyhf{} \fancyhf[HLE,HRO]{\thepage} \fancyhf[HRE,HLO]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}\clearpage\newpage`. In all cases the previous page header is missing "Acknowledgement".

Comment: You do need the header settings before the `\clearpage`.  So remove the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\markboth` to set the marks manually:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[acronym,xindy,toc,nomain]{glossaries}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\setlength{\headheight}{15.2pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhf[HLE,HRO]{\thepage}
\fancyhf[HRE,HLO]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}

\makeglossaries
%\setacronymstyle{long-sc-short}
\newacronym{AB}{AB}{Alpha Beta}

\begin{document}
\title{\LaTeX{}}
\author{Author's Name}
\maketitle

\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
\markboth{\MakeUppercase{Acknowledgements}}{}
\Blindtext
\gls{AB}

\printacronyms
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]